# DataGridView: How to allow comma and dot as a separators at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, binding, formatting

I have a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn which is binded to a property. I want to allow user to input numbers no matter what he uses to separate decimals. Also I don't need spaces or commas to separate thousads.

It's simple:

1.908 = 1.908

1,908 = 1.908

And if there is no way to specify format string, can i Replace(",",".") before binding? Or any other way?

Thank you. (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You _can_ use `Replace` but I do not recommend this. Because in such a case, user _might_ put `.` for thousand separator as well which can be ambiguous for a culture setting you use. I would suggest to put some validation in your UI part to supply _proper_ format for a decimal instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crete another property of String type which will be bounded to that column.
Then set/read value of original property through this

```
public class YourBindableItem
{
    public decimal OriginalValue { get; set; }

    public decimal ParsedValue 
    {
        get { return this.OriginalValue.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            string forParse = 
                value.Replace(",", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
            decimal temp = 0;
            if(decimal.TryParse(forParse, 
                                out temp,
                                Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == true)
            {
                this.OriginalValue = temp;
            }
            //if value wasn't parsed succesfully, original value will be returned
            this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameOf(this.ParsedValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridView` already formats according to the regional settings for the current user, at least if you data bind to an object data source and the property is numeric (i.e. not a `string`).

You can test this by opening `Region and Language` in Windows and switching between e.g. the `English (United States)` format and `Swedish (Sweden)`. In the former case, the input `2.718` will parse correctly while in the second `2,718` will. You'll have to run without debugging in VS in order to load fresh settings.

(I would not suggest trying to parse both comma and dot as a decimal separator for the same user, if you're thinking of doing that. That's not the expected behavior for most users and it would lead to bugs if the user should happen to use the thousand separator too.)